# Divs moving over ~200px to the right on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm having a curious problem with mobile devices. I have three divs which are set position:absolute;, and I used left:; to get them positioned directly under three corresponding buttons. Everything fits together beautifully on a desktop, but on a mobile device all three of the divs are moved over to the right about 200px. I also have a div at the bottom of the page containing a facebook page plugin which is behaving in a similar manner. Here's a screenshot of what I mean, using Chrome's mobile emulation dev tool:[Here http://gruntwork.us/reelindi/test/screenshot.jpg](http://gruntwork.us/reelindi/test/screenshot.jpg)

Here's the code for the divs in question:

CSS:

```
div.filmMakers{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    width: 15.4%;
    max-width: 15.4%;
    height: auto;
    left: 364;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville',sans-serif;
}
div.features{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    width: 13%;
    max-width: 13%;
    height: auto;
    left: 612;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville',sans-serif;
}
div.clients{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    width: 11%;
    max-width: 11%;
    height: auto;
    left: 832;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville',sans-serif;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="filmMakers">
    <p style="text-align:center; margin-top: -5px; margin-bottom: 1px;"><strong>Multi-Media Professionals.</strong><br>Creative journals, step-by-step tutorials, tech reviews, blogs.</p>
</div>
<div class="features">
    <p style="text-align:center; margin-top: -5px; margin-bottom: 1px;"><strong>Upcoming Features.</strong><br>Project investment opportunities, coming soon to the silver screen.</p>
</div>
<div class="clients">
    <p style="text-align:center; margin-top: -5px; margin-bottom: 1px;"><strong>Production Interests.</strong><br>Work with us to build your ideas.</p>
</div>
```

The facebook page plugin's HTML:

```
<div style="margin-left: 200px; margin-top: -85px; margin-right: 100px; width:400px; border: solid #fff; border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px; font-size: 0.8em;">
    <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/reelindi/" data-width="400" data-height="100" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="false"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/reelindi/"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/reelindi/">Reel Indi</a></blockquote></div></div>
</div>
```

Any help with this would be appreciated. Pure CSS and jQuery are both options, but I'm not particularly experienced with either when it comes to mobile dev.

Comment: Are you using any `@media` queries? All your absolute divs (yyou are missing `.filmMakers` styles btw) have static `left` positions and your facebook plugin has a `margin-left:200px;`

Comment: Oh dear, pasted the wrong div. Fixed. I'm not particularly familiar with @media queries and no, I don't have any in the stylesheet.

Comment: You will need `@media` queries in your stylesheet to change your `left` values at smaller screen sizes. A `div` that is positioned `absolute` and has a static `left` value like `612px` (you are missing the px btw) will always be 612 pixels from the left even on screen that is only 500 pixels wide.

Comment: You can see examples of common media style breakpoints [here](https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints)

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, I'm basically going to have to rewrite the majority of the style sheet individually for most every common device and stick each iteration into a different @media query, then cross my fingers and hope it doesn't break on some oddball device? Are there any tools to aide in figuring what the em/px values need to be, or is it just a trial and error process?

Comment: This is why most people use a responsive CSS framework like Bootstrap. Absolute position can be dangerous in responsive design, but if I were you I would try using a relative unit like `%` instead of `px` for your `left` value (i.e. `left:20%;`) and see if you can get the results you want. Do you have a live site you can link to or is it all local?

Comment: The site is currently live at http://gruntwork.us/reelindi/test/

Comment: Well, by converting the static left:'s to % values, I've gotten the page to display more-or-less correctly on small devices, however this has presented the issue of the text being pretty far off center in desktop browsers. I think I can fix this with a @media query, but for some odd reason my media query seems to be being ignored entirely.

This is the media query in question:
`@media screen and (min-width: 1024) {
 div.filmMakers{
  left: 50%;
 }
 body{
  background-color: black;
 }
 div.body{background-color:black;}
 div.footer{background-color:black;}
}`

Any idea why, @zgood ?

Comment: The query is at the bottom of the stylesheet and I added a `meta` tag to the head of the HTML, but it still seems to have no effect. I added the background-color bits to confirm that it's being entirely ignored. What gives?

Comment: You forgot the `px` in this: `(min-wiidth: 1024)` should be `(min-wiidth: 1024px)`

Comment: maybe something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/npLeaary/1/) would work?

Comment: That works absolutely perfectly! You sir, are a code ninja. Thanks so much!